# MaterialUI styled components defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

We can declare defaultProps in a styled component as follows

```
const StyledComponent = styled("div")(
  ({theme}) => ({
    ....code
  })
)
```

then declaring defaultProps as follows:

```
StyledComponent.defaultProps = {
  propA: value,
  propB: value
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to declare defaultProps and inject it directly within the `styled` declaration?

Here is an example of trying to pass `direction` to a custom component based on the `Grid` component from MUI:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-beaver-du3mb5?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

**StyledComponent.defaultProps** properties could be added directly into the StyledComponent declaration like this:

```
const StyledComponent = styled("div")(
  ({theme, ...otherProps}) => ({
    propA: value,
    propB: value,
    ...otherProps
  })
);
```

Using [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) allows propA and propB to act as defaults that can be overridden by `otherProps`.

`otherProps` are passed into the component via props sent to StyledComponent. For example:

```
<StyledComponent
  propA={ valueA }
  propB={ valueB }
  propC={ valueC }
/>
```

## UPDATE

The codesandbox example (sample code is displayed below) confuses the CSS property *[direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)* (e.g. ltr and rtl) with the **[direction](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/#props)** prop on the MUI Grid component. The CSS-in-JS object returned by styled components is setting CSS properties, not MUI component props. The Grid component prop **direction** sets the *flex-direction* CSS property (not the *direction* CSS property). A corrected code sample is below.

Code from the codesandbox example:

```
const StyledComponent = styled(Grid)(({ theme, ...otherProps }) => ({
  direction: "column",
  color: "darkslategray",
  backgroundColor: "aliceblue",
  padding: 8,
  borderRadius: 4
}));
```

This corrected version below assumes that your intention was to set the MUI Grid component prop **direction** (since the CSS property *direction* does not have 'column' as a valid value).

```
const StyledComponent = styled(Grid)(({ theme, ...otherProps }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  color: 'darkslategray',
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: 8,
  borderRadius: 4
}));
```

Comment: That is what I thought but there are instances with core MUI components where this doesn't work. Here is an example trying to pass direction to Grid container: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-beaver-du3mb5?file=/demo.tsx